# Issue with font rendering java 1.8 on Fedora 21

Tags: java, android, oracle, intellij-idea, android-studio

What is up with the blurry and thin fonts on the latest JDK8? Same issue exist with JDK7.

On JDK6 the fonts looked clear and a bit bolder, much more readable.I should also note that the issue only appear in the editor and in the applications themselves. The menus and setting fonts render correctly in both IDE.

I'm going all in with IntelliJ and Android Studio as I can't stand eclipse anymore, so I gotta switch to Oracle JDK as I'm having problems with OpenJDK and android projects. However running Oracle or OpenJDK doesn't change the issue.

Images that show the problem. [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKO7C.png]
[image: https://i.imgur.com/e5BQVa3.png]

I've been spending hours trying to understand and solve this problem, though none of the fixes I've tried has worked.

Is it possible to solve this or should I give up android development on Linux?